# PyAudio How do you group frequency ranges together

Tags: python, fft, pyaudio

I followed a tutorial on how to get sound data with pyaudio. It shows the amplitude of sound on certain frequencies.

```
import pyaudio
import struct
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import fft

CHUNK = 2**10
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream=p.open(format=FORMAT,channels=CHANNELS,rate=RATE,input=True,
              output=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

data = struct.unpack(str(CHUNK*CHANNELS) + 'h', stream.read(CHUNK))
fft_data = fft(data)
fft_data = np.abs(fft_data[:CHUNK]) * 2 / (256 * CHUNK)
print(fft_data)
```

Now I want to group these together so that I can make a simple bar graph showing the amplitude of certain ranges of frequencies. When I run this code it returns the amplitude of 1024 frequencies, so I tried using this function to group them into 32 groups.

```
def split_freq(freq): # splits given sound frequencies into groups of frequencies to feed into turtle
    freq_ranges = []
    for i in range(len(freq)-1): # split the frequencies into 32 groups
        if i % abs((len(freq)//32)) == 0: # create new array every time i is a multiple of the number of frequencies divided by 32
            if len(freq_ranges) > 0:
                freq_ranges[len(freq_ranges)-2] = freq_ranges[len(freq_ranges)-2] / (len(freq)//32)
            freq_ranges.append(0)
        freq_ranges[len(freq_ranges)-1] = freq_ranges[len(freq_ranges)-1] + freq[i]
    return [i * 400 for i in freq_ranges]
```

My frequency grouping method seems to work, but when I feed in a certain tone the bar graph doesn't change in any meaningful way. Does anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `rfft` instead of `fft` since the data you are transforming only contains real values. The `rfft` should provide a more meaningful representation of the data.

The way you are splitting the data has no real physical meaning as far as I can see. I would recommend grouping by frequency bands; you can use a list comprehension to do this by grouping values in bins and then apply a function like sum or average:

```
n = fourier_data.size // 32    # 32 frequency bands
bands = [sum(fft_data[i:(i + n)]) for i in range(0, fft_data.size, n)]
```

or:

```
from statistics import mean

n = fourier_data.size // 32    # 32 frequency bands
bands = [mean(fft_data[i:(i + n)]) for i in range(0, fft_data.size, n)]
```

Comment: I just tried your approach and it seems to work a bit better. I tried inputting different frequency tones into the program and it seems to show that both the high and low frequencies have high values. When feeding in low frequencies the high and low frequencies are highest in the program, and on high frequencies, all of the frequencies are pretty much the same in the program. You also say that I should be using rfft to get real values but I am using np.abs to make the imaginary numbers real.

Comment: Right, maybe you should cut the very low frequencies by excluding the first elements of the array.

Comment: Also,  `fft` returns values in a way similar to this: constant, low freq, high freq, conjugate low freq, conjugate high freq, because of the way a complex fourier transform works, while `rfft` should return values like: constant, low freq, high freq. That's the reason `rfft` may give you a better representation.